# BlackBerry add new contact to address book

Tags: blackberry, java-me

the Blackberry app I'm working at requires me to export all app contacts to the BB address book. I'm able to retrieve the ContactList and create a new contact. However, when I call

```
AddressBookArguments entry = 
    new AddressBookArguments(AddressBookArguments.ARG_NEW, contact);

Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_ADDRESSBOOK, entry);
```

I'll have the new contact page of the address book poped up and have to manually press the save button. I can't let the user do this for all the contacts.

So my question is, is there a way to auto-save these newly created contacts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can certainly create new contacts programmatically.

Here is some sample code that creates a new contact with a company name and an email address. You can extend this with other fields, such as name, phone number, etc.

```
ContactList contactList = (ContactList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(
    PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.WRITE_ONLY);

Contact newContact = contactList.createContact();
newContact.addString(Contact.ORG, Contact.STRING, "ACME Corporation");

if ( contactList.isSupportedField(Contact.EMAIL) ) 
{
   newContact.addString(Contact.EMAIL, Contact.STRING, "johndoe@acme.com");
}

newContact.commit();
```